# table column contain query

Tags: php, mysql

here's my problem, i tried to select data from table A have column fill query which select data from table B, select data from table C. but table A,B, and C not related. example like below.

```
Table A
ID   Title        Query 
1    one       select note_nbr from table B
2    two       select note_nbr from table C  
3    three     select note_nbr from table D

I want output
ID  Title       note_nbr
1    one       122  (from table B)
1    one       153  (from table B)
2    two       224  (from  table C)
3    three     713  (from  table D)
3    three     224  (from  table D)
```

Query i have tried with subquery, but i dont know how to join because not related. name of column just example

```
SELECT 
      TES.ID AS ID,
      TES.NTFY_TTL AS TITLE,
      NBR.NBR_ORD AS NOTE 
FROM
     (SELECT 
           A.ID AS ID,
           A.NTFY_TTL AS NTFY_TTL, 
           FROM A.ID A
     ) TES
LEFT JOIN
     (
     SELECT
          B.ID_NOTE AS ID
          B.NOTE_NBR AS NBR_ORD
     FROM 
          B.ID_NOTE B
UNION ALL
     SELECT
          C.ID_NOTE AS ID
          C.NOTE_NBR AS NBR_ORD
     FROM 
          C.ID_NOTE C 
     ) 
NBR ON TES.ID
```

Comment: it is for sure a bad db design. consider creating note_nbr table where will be foreign key ID from table A

Comment: i tried to make notification for note have problem, so i should select all note number to my notification table.

Comment: There must be some sort of relationship otherwise how do you know that  one should only be linked to table b?

Comment: so it impossible to get data from table not related ?

Comment: No.It is possible using a cross join but you won't get the result you want see answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to join without a relationship but I don't see how you expect only one to join to a (for example)

drop table if exists a,b,c,d;

```
create table a(id int, ntf_ttl varchar(6));
create table b(note_nbr int);
create table c(note_nbr int);
create table d(note_nbr int);

insert into a values (1,'one'),(2,'two'),(3,'Threee');
insert into b values(123),(153);
insert into c values(224);
insert into d values(713),(224);

select id,ntf_ttl,note_nbr from a cross join b

result
+------+---------+----------+
| id   | ntf_ttl | note_nbr |
+------+---------+----------+
|    1 | one     |      123 |
|    1 | one     |      153 |
|    2 | two     |      123 |
|    2 | two     |      153 |
|    3 | Threee  |      123 |
|    3 | Threee  |      153 |
+------+---------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: what i want is, all data from query which select from table b, it display in id from table a based rows query in id table  a.

Comment: It is not at clear to me what you are asking for, can you try rephrasing using the data model in my answer.

Comment: sorry it hard to say in english, my english bad. okey

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into a values (1,'ID'),(1,'TITLE'),(1,'select note_nbr from table b(*this column query)');
insert into a values (2,'ID'),(2,'TITLE'),(2,'select note_nbr from table c(*this column query)');
insert into b values(123);
insert into c values(123); 

not like this, result
+------+---------+----------+
| id   | ntf_ttl | note_nbr |
+------+---------+----------+
|    1 | one     |      123 |
|    1 | one     |      153 |
|    2 | two     |      123 |
|    2 | two     |      153 |
|    3 | Threee  |      123 |
|    3 | Threee  |      153 |
+------+---------+----------+
```

i hope u get what i say. so when all data in query it display in id 1 in table a . so the output

```
ID  note_nbr
1   123(*from table b)
2   123(*from table c)
```